# Insert value from a form into my database table only if it doesn't exist already in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are similar questions and answers on this topic already but none have helped me or at least I can't work out how to make it apply to me. This should be very simple but I can't make it work.

I have a single table called customers with a single column called customerName I have a form with a single text box where you enter the customer name. When the form is submited either the name doesn't already exist in the table and gets entered, or it does exist and won't be entered.

How do I write the SQL query to enter the customer name only if it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 1):

The query for adding the customer name is like this

```
INSERT INTO customers(customerName) VALUES ([name]);
```

But, before that, make the `customerName` field unique. It will prevent the same value enters twice.